# PHP thread do not end

Tags: php, multithreading

I tried to implement multithreading in php to fetch data from a data source parallely.
But in the process, the threads i create to fetch the data continue to remain in the memory, even after the fetching.
This is the class that i call

```
class ClassName extends Thread {
    public function __construct($i){
        $this->i=$i;
    }
    public function run(){
        // functionCallToDataSource($this->i);
    }
}
```

and i call this class here (in a loop).

```
$workers = new ClassName(parameter);
$workers->start();
$workers->kill();       //this isnt working
```

This kill() doesnt seem to work for me, as the memory is not reduced after the functions have been performed.
I have to restart my server to free the blocked memory

Comment: Do you want to destroy your obj? IF yes use: `unset()`

Comment: it will unset the object. what i want is to unset the memory used by the thread started from this object

Comment: Please post the actual code you're having a problem with, not the snippet where you think the problem is.